# InvalidFormatException for ISO 8601, JsonFormat, TimeZone, and +0000 at the end

Tags: java, spring, jackson

### Situation

I have a java application calling a micro service through feign and I am getting the following exception:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException:
>   Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String
>   "2019-05-08T14:41:39.803+0000": expected format
>   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.XXX"

I have inpointed that this format we get from the server is ISO8601 from the tests located at:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/jdk/DateDeserializationTest.java#L157

I am trying the following @JsonFormat annotations but they are failing:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.XXX", lenient = OptBoolean.TRUE) private Date creationDate;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.XXX", lenient = OptBoolean.TRUE) private Date  lastUpdatedDate;
```

### Question

So...apologies for the really simple question but:

**How do I deal with the +0000 at the end in order to make the de-serializing finally work?**

Comment: Add information how the annotations they are failing

Comment: @Leszek Gruchała Cannot deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String "2019-05-08T14:41:39.803+0000": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.XXX"

Comment: Try with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` or `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I deal with the `+0000` at the end in order to make the deserializing finally work?

[`@JsonFormat`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) expects a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)-compatible pattern definition.

So `Z` or `X` could be used to indicate a GMT offset value, depending on what the offset format is like.

The full patterns you are looking for are `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` or `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`, as shown in the examples of the [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation.